# How to write a custom find-file function

Tags: eshell, find-file

I want to write a set of functions that call specific files, not by a specific name, but the newest file (with a certain suffix) in the directory. So far I've got

```
(defun org_lisp_dir ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/org/babeltest/c.org"))
```

but that doesn't get me the latest .org file. To do this I believe I need to use something like `(eshell/ls something)`, but I'm not sure how to use `(eshell/ls)` or integrate a complex eshell command into my code. The actual command would be something like `ls -Art *.org | tail -n 1` which works just fine in eshell, BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `shell-command-to-string` to get a shell command's output. From `C-h f shell-command-to-string`:

> shell-command-to-string is a compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.
>
> (shell-command-to-string COMMAND)
>
> Execute shell command COMMAND and return its output as a string.

For example, on my machine, your shell command gives

```el
(let ((default-directory "~/org/"))     ; Ending slash is necessary
  (shell-command-to-string "ls -Art *.org | tail -n 1"))
    ⇒ "todo.org
"
```

*Note*: I have changed directory by setting `default-directory` before running the shell command, mostly because `ls(1)` can't tell file's full path. And there is also a trailing newline, which is not part of filename and needs to be removed, you can remove that from elisp or from shell.

---

Here is a command named `foo` for opening newest `.org` file in `~/org/` directory (non-recursively).

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory "~/org/"))
    (find-file (shell-command-to-string "ls -Art *.org | tail -n 1 | tr -d '\n'"))))
```

`tr(1)` is used here to remove trailing newline.

Comment: `shell-command-to-string` looks like the ticket. So it is not advisable to use `eshell/ls` or `eshell-do-ls`?

Comment: @147pm I don't know how they can be used in ordinary lisp code (that is, outside eshell), they're not documented in eshell's manual. Though, I know `(eshell-command-result "ls -Art *.org | tail -n 1")` will produce the same output as `shell-command-to-string`, once you've launched eshell for at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Use `directory-files` to get the list of files in a directory.

Then loop over that list (e.g. `dolist`), examining the last-modified dates using function `file-attributes` to identify the most recently modified file(s).  Or you can use function `file-newer-than-file-p` to filter the list.

Use `find-file` (not `find-file-noselect`) when you have identified the file(s) you want to edit (I'm assuming you want to edit them).

(However, I don't think that the original *creation* date is available, if that's the information you are after.)